# draw a curve that bends around multiple points in php?

Tags: php

I want to draw a dynamically generated line that bends around n points in php, depending on input. I know I could use image arc and painstakingly get the curves to overlap at the proper angles so that multiple curves give the illusion of a single bendy line. But is there is an easier/cleaner way?

I basically want to do this:

[image]

Comment: Just draw parabola's http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagearc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish the client side to render this I recommend using the canvas tag
See reference here: **http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-bezier-curves/**

Or use imagemagick backend if you with the server side to do it

look up **Bezier Primitive** on page **http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#bezier**

Answer (score 1):

You could use ImageMagick to create an image of the output you want. I've always found it pretty straightforward.

eg
http://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#bezier
http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.bezier.php